# Flyout with within a listview itemClick not work

Tags: xaml, uwp

I created a simple usercontrol , a listbox and a button , when you click on the button opens a flyout with within a listview ,
my problem is that the ItemClick on item of listview does not work, does not access the method.
this is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Column="1">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind font}" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick"></ListView>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I inserted a breakpoint in the method but in the execution does not access the method .
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is just another property you have to activate in the ListView to make the ItemClick event work IsItemClickEnabled="True" :

```
<Button Grid.Column="1">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                <ListView  IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
                    <ListView.Items>
                        <ListViewItem>
                            <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>
                            <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
                        </ListViewItem>
                    </ListView.Items>
                    </ListView>
                </Flyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Right , I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

**SelectionChanged** event of **ListvIew** can also be subscribed for achieving the result.